# Hibernate delete many to many lazy collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My Entity classes are:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dt_creation", nullable = false)
    private Date dtCreation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dt_maj", nullable = false)
    private Date dtMaj;

    // bi-directional many-to-one 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quality", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<RQulityUser> RQualityUser;


@Entity
public class RQualityUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dt_creation", nullable = false)
    private Date dtCreation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dt_maj", nullable = false)
    private Date dtMaj;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Questionnaire
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private User user;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to QualitePersonne
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cd_quality_user", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Quality quality;
```

When I get a user and I try to clear the list of RQualityUser i dosen't work :

```
 User user = em.getByid(11);
 user.getRQualityUserList().clear();
```

Hibernate doesn't delete the record in the relation table ?

Answer (score 0):

"Lazy loading" means that an entity will be loaded only when you actually accesses the entity for the first time.

When you do

```
user.getRQualityUserList() // Still contains nothing.
```

So you are clearing empty list and afterwards when you will use this will call data from DB.

Comment: so, the solution would be to transform all lazy fetch in the RQualityUser  class to eager ???

Comment: It depends, If Eager fetching will hit you performance, you must use it where its needed. For now if you just `call list.size();` and then clear your list will make your list empty.

Comment: I used your solution but still not woeking, when I debug the list get cleared but when I set the new list I got an exception that the element is present in the database ?? why this is happing even when the list get cleared ???

Comment: if you are trying to delete elements then delete all child objects as well

Comment: When you call any method of `user.getRQualityUserList()` Hibernate fetches this lazy association. So  `user.getRQualityUserList().clear()` load the data from a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this

```
User user = em.getByid(11);
user.getRQualityUserList().clear();
```

With an opened persistent context and inside a transaction Hibernate should delete records.

If you don't have a transaction you should use it.

If you do `clear()` with a closed persistent context you should update `user` to delete records.